# JavaScript - Prompt inside function doesn't appear on screen, but does outside the function

Tags: javascript

I am building a rock, paper, scissors project which is supposed to take 5 rounds. The user will get a prompt and input either "rock", "paper", or "scissors". When I write the code like this:

```
let playerSelection = prompt("Rock, paper ou scissors?").toLowerCase();


let game = function() {
  for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {

    compare(playerSelection, computerPlay);
      if (compare === "You win!") {
       playerScore++;
      }
      else if (compare === "You lose!") {
        computerScore++;
      }
      else if (compare === "It's a tie!") {
  
      }

 }
}
```

The prompt is prompted and I get to input something, however it only happens once and the loop doesn't work. When I put the prompt inside the loop, like this:

```
let game = function() {
  for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    
    let playerSelection = prompt("Rock, paper ou scissors?").toLowerCase();

    compare(playerSelection, computerPlay);
      if (compare === "You win!") {
       playerScore++;
      }
      else if (compare === "You lose!") {
        computerScore++;
      }
      else if (compare === "It's a tie!") {
  
      }

 }
}
```

The prompt never shows up!
How can I solve this and make it prompt 5 times?

Comment: try run that function 5 times??

Comment: Do you run the `game` function? Also, your `compare` function should not be compared to strings. Compare its result instead: `const result = compare(playerSelection, computerPlay);`

Comment: Where does `compare` as in `if (compare === "You win!") {` come from? There's a function named `compare` too. ??

Comment: Yeah, there's another function called compare previously in the code. I omitted it for brevity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you are not calling the function.
use

```
game();
```

after function definition

Comment: Yeah, that should work (I can't believe I didn't see this)

Answer (score 0):

I think there is some error in your compare function. checkout the snippet below its working fine.

```js
const compare = function(playerSelection, computerPlay) {

  // write your logic here
  return "You win!";
}
let game = function() {
  for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    
    let playerSelection = prompt("Rock, paper ou scissors?").toLowerCase();
    const outputs = ["rock", "paper", "scissor"];
    compare(playerSelection, Math.floor(Math.random()*3));
      if (compare === "You win!") {
       playerScore++;
      }
      else if (compare === "You lose!") {
        computerScore++;
      }
      else if (compare === "It's a tie!") {
  
      }

 }
}

game();
```